# How to choose an item from a dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can choose an item from a dropdown menu?

This is the Error massage
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.0.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="select2-massbending-result-mnkp-1739ADED802119FAFE3AE2CDA03E0075"]"}
(Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
Command: [37875cebf5ae802a1b5455859349376c, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id="select2-massbending-result-mnkp-1739ADED802119FAFE3AE2CDA03E0075"]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 102.0.5005.115, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4..., userDataDir: C:\Users\OMAR~1.ELS\AppData...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64998}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:64998/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 102.0.5005.115, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 37875cebf5ae802a1b5455859349376c

The Browser open and log in the dropdown is pressed, but it doesn't pick any element in it

```
<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 207.953px; left: 80px;"><span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 501px;"><span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox"></span><span class="select2-results"><ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-massbending-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"><li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">select</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-qv5z-E17969A3569FFFB9FE38C4DA499D6B7C" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">الاهلى للخدمات الطبية</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-09vf-3635DD9DC6F14B9F7531A4B4AF17C4F8" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">EGYCare</li><li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-massbending-result-2pqn-E459950A60D539CFA196AA887ABF13F1" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Seif Health Care</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-z8ev-C7D55B7B6FCA0FCE1640BC9FE634523E" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Prime Health Egypt</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-d4gu-DB1E9157DE264E4CAF25D2B872C926B7" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Ciaf Health Care</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-oh0b-638D4A97AE9CB54A0259EB0FF40D7A5F" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Future</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-8et4-8B9348FE31D8C944EC8D18F5C94E0608" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">MedSure</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-vwyx-06E8A65DC99874AAC26EB392F7A9AC31" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Queuing test E</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-4cqc-A350E8628BE44651F86CBF3B45B8ADCD" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Misr Healthcare</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-6dky-AB940187B0B10A0838E133BA0E3A7F05" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">INAYA EGYPT</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-massbending-result-gtoo-E7B06E1096A9AE53900CDB15DE476F92" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Belshifa</li></ul></span></span></span>
```

Code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Nicedeer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //Open Nicedeer
        driver.get("http://www.nicedeer.net/");
        //Enter Username
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"UserName\"]"));
        element.sendKeys("xxxx");
        //Enter Password
        WebElement elementPass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]"));
        elementPass.sendKeys("xxx");
        //Login to account
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginBTN\"]"));
        button.click();
        //Choose Payer
        WebElement payer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-massbending-container\"]"));
        payer.click();

        //Select Payer
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-massbending-result-mnkp-1739ADED802119FAFE3AE2CDA03E0075\"]")).click();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the value from this drop down by doing this:

*- First click on drop down element like:*

```
driver.findElement(By.id("correct_id")).click();
```

*- Second `click` on element you want to select*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
```

You can use below `xpath` for the dropdown element, eg, for Future

```
- //li[contains(text(),'Future')]
```

**OR**

```
- //*[normalize-space()='Future']
```

Comment: Add the code and error message in the question

Comment: Have you tried the `xpath` provided in the answer ? also your code is unclear, try the answer

Comment: I updated the code with error massage

Comment: you are getting `NoSuchElementException` on loctor `id='select2-massbending-result-mnkp-1739ADED802119FAFE3AE2CDA03E0075'` have you tried the provded `xpath` in the answer ?